# PHP Parse Error: /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php on line 26

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I've encountered this error in  my apache2 error.log while accessing a project running on WSL.

```
[Tue Feb 28 14:42:17.331656 2017] [:error] [pid 25334] [client 127.0.0.1:52043] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /mnt/c/development/public_html/xxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/I18n/functions.php on line 26
```

I'm running:

- Cake 3.4.2
- PHP 7.0.16-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
- On Windows Subsystem for Linux

I have other cake projects working fine on this setup but none that are v3.4*.

I have no idea how to solve this problem as it's in the Cake core. Any advice on how to proceed from here would be great.

Please ask if you need any more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There is no 3.4.3 branch (yet)

There is no `3.4.3` branch (yet), double check that you are looking at the correct info. Maybe it was published by accident and has been retracted, if you really have version `3.4.3`, try reinstalling your applications dependencies.

### Ensure that PHP used by Apache PHP is up to date

Also make sure that your server is actually using the PHP version that you think it does, the Apache PHP module and the PHP CLI binary are two different things, and the FPM/CGI binary usually also isn't used on the CLI, ie the CLI and the server often times use different versions.

The error message you are referencing suggests that PHP couldn't handle the `...` variadic function operator, which would mean that Apache is using a PHP version prior `5.6`

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo the correct version is 3.4.2. `php -v` returns `PHP 7.0.16-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 ...` is there another way to check what version is being used?

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` via a script running on the server, or try `dpkg --list | grep php` and look for `libapach2` or `php*-fpm`. @KevWilson

Comment: That was it. I had to disable php5 and enable php7 on apache. Thanks a lot